# I am trying to use data from SQLite to populate a custom array adaptor i have already created

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is the code below where i am getting the error is Bmi bmi = new Bmi(); I have tried to figure it, could be i have spent so long looking at it just cant see it. this way worked with the custom adaptor  newBmi(new Bmi(bmiLabel, bmiDate, heightStr, weightStr ));

```
        public List<Bmi> getAllBmi() {
    List<Bmi> bmis = new ArrayList<>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + T_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            Bmi bmi = new Bmi();
            bmi.setWeight(cursor.getString(1));
            bmi.setHeight(cursor.getString(2));
            bmi.setBmiLabel(cursor.getString(3));
            bmi.setBmiDate(cursor.getString(4));

            bmis.addAll((Collection<? extends Bmi>) bmi);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }


    return bmis;
}



















            package ie.wit.fitnessmadeeasy.ie.app.models;

            import java.util.List;

          /**
           * Created by mikel_000 on 05/03/2017.
           */

             public class Bmi {
           //public double height;
            // public double weight;
            public String bmiLabel;
            public String bmiDate;
            public String weight;
            public String height;
```

//  public Bmi ( String bmiLabel, String bmiDate)
  //  {

```
   // this.height = height;
   // this.weight = weight;
   // this.bmiLabel = bmiLabel;
  //  this.bmiDate = bmiDate;
```

//  }

```
          public Bmi(String weight, String height, String bmiLabel, String bmiDate) {
             this.bmiLabel = bmiLabel;
             this.bmiDate = bmiDate;
             this.weight = weight;
             this.height = height;
}




public void addAll(String bmiLabel, String bmiDate) {
    this.bmiLabel = bmiLabel;
    this.bmiDate = bmiDate;
}

public void setWeight(String weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public void setBmiLabel(String bmiLabel) {
    this.bmiLabel = bmiLabel;
}

public void setBmiDate(String bmiDate) {
    this.bmiDate = bmiDate;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any exception ?

Comment: what it says is Bmi() cannot be apllied to String, String, String, String,

Comment: expected parameters weight, height, bmiLabel, bmiDate. there is nothing coming up for actual parameters

Comment: Can you show your Bmi class ?

Comment: yeah one sec ill put it up

Comment: Sorry for the way it came out, it always messes up when i add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your Bmi class. You can create Bmi instance by using below code

```
        String weight = cursor.getString(1);
        String height = cursor.getString(2);
        String bmiLabel = cursor.getString(3);
        String bmiDate = cursor.getString(4);
        Bmi bmi = new Bmi(weight, height, bmilabel, bmiDate);
```

Comment: i'll try that there now